# Writing code to fire the last method to throw an exception in a multi-threaded web app

Tags: c#, .net

I was writing some try-catch blocks for various methods today, and thought to myself it would be good to have  utility method which would automatically call the method again for a number of times specified in a parameter, at a certain time.

However, I thought to myself, the method/property etc which will cause an exception will be at the top of the stacktrace (do property calls get put on the stacktrace?) in a single threaded application (so an application with no code relating to threading). So I can simply get the method name at the top and dynamically call it again.

So I would have code like:

string s = StackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethodName; (I can't remember the exact syntax).

With this method, I can execute it using an activator or one of several other ways.

But in a multi-threaded application, I could have several methods firing at once and I wouldn't know which one finishes first/last. So I can't expect a method for which I write a try-catch block to be at the top of the stack.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

**Please don't do this.**  It's a really, really, really, really, really *bad idea*.

Maybe not as bad as deleting files randomly, if the hard drive runs out of room - but just about as bad.

Answer (score 1):

While I question the need for an auto retrying mechanism (does randomly retrying really help you out in so many situations that you need a utility method?) - using StackTrace and Reflection is, at best, a terribly complicated solution.

Not that I suggest that anyone actually *use* this code, but I'd probably go with a delegate based approach to this particular problem:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static void Try(this Action a, int maxTries) {
       new (Func<bool>(() => { a(); return true; })).Try(maxTries);
    }

    public static TResult Try<TResult>(this Func<TResult> f, int maxTries) {
       Exception lastException = null;

       for (int i = 0; i < maxTries; i++) {
          try {
              return f();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              lastException = ex;
          }
       }

       throw lastException;
    }
}
```

Usage is a bit unorthodox, but fairly clear I think:

```
// Set a property
new Action(() => myObject.Property = 5).Try(5);

// With a return value
var count = new Func<int>(() => myList.Count).Try(3);
```

You can't inline a lambda to a method, but you could have a somewhat fluent interface:

```
Utilities.Try(
   () => MyObject.Property = 5
).Repeat(5);
```

And multi line methods:

```
Utilities.Try(() => {
   MyObject.Property1 = 5;
   MyObject.Property2 = 6;
   MyObject.Property3 = 7;
}).Repeat(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark's code is probably better, but here's mine...

If you **really** want to do something like this, I'd use code something like this.  Yes, you still have to manually call it, but your idea of indiscriminately retrying ALL excepting methods is a really, really bad idea.

```
public class TryAgain
{
    public delegate void CodeToTryAgain ();

    public static void Repeat<E>(int count, CodeToTryAgain code) where E : Exception
    {
        while (count-- > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                code();
                return;
            }
            catch (E ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught an {0} : {1}", typeof(E).Name, ex.Message);
                // ignoring it!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you'd call your failing method, `ThrowTwice`, or whatever you want to do, like this:

```
TryAgain.Repeat<MyException>(5, delegate()
{
    ThrowTwice();
});
```

In this example, the Repeat method will ignore all exceptions of type MyException, trying to call ThrowTwice up to 5 times...

You can add your own sleeping and time-outs, and whatever.